# iPython Notebook Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, canopy

I always used iPython notebook with Python 2.7.6 on Mac OS X Yosemite. Now I have a notebook I only can use with Python 3. I installed Python 3.4.3 and tried to launch notebook with the command "ipython3 notebook", but this doesn't work... I also updated the iPython package with Canopy. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `but this doesn't work...`  - can you be more specific here?

Comment: Sure! I get this error back in my terminal: "-bash: ipython3: command not found" Instead of opening a browser window with iPython notebook

Comment: Looks like the symlink does not exist. Does `python3 -m IPython` work?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments! I deleted iPython with Canopy and installed it again and now it words fine.

Comment: Each Python installation has its own set of packages, including IPython - if you install a new version of Python, you need to install IPython in that Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed iPython from my Mac with Canopy and installed it again, now it works perfect!